# gcc arm-none-eabi binaries don't run

Tags: macos, gcc, cortex-m, binaries

I build a cross compile toolchain on OSX with:
binutils-2.23.52
gcc-4.6.4
gcc-core-4.6.4
gcc-g++-4.6.4
gdb-7.6.1
gmp-4.3.2
mpc-1.0.1
mpfr-2.4.2
newlib-2.0.0
for the target EFM32 wich is a ARM Cortex-m3, so the gcc target is arm-none-eabi.
All compiled fine.
But making programs with this toolchain like blink.c don't actually run on the EFM32 board.
I checked the blink.bin I did with a binary created with a IAR commercial toolchain delivered in the demos from energymicro, also gcc based and the they look very different internally (as expected :).
So has my toolchain wrong libs/versions or is it simply a matter of gcc/ld/ar switches wrong and what would be the steps to systematicly analyse this?

Comment: Did it flash correctly?  Does the generated code look reasonable?

Comment: I flashed demo binaries that work and then changed the filename of the binary to the one I compiled. So all good there. But the top few houndred bytes of the binaries have mostly zeros, where in the working one are a few instructions. Then the rest of the binary files both are pretty much packed with instructions.

Comment: So what does it look like when you break in at the first instruction and start stepping?

Comment: Well flashing got done with the demo loader not with gdb - Eclipse says this after some debug commands get send: An internal error occurred during: "Label Job".
java.lang.NullPointerException 
And the is not source available and on stepping further : can not find bounds of current function

Comment: ok now - the first gdb step is in the startup file:
 /* Set up the stack pointer */
 asm("ldr sp,=_estack\n\t");

Comment: it is a cortex-m4, the first word of the binary is the stack address there is no need for a ldr sp instruction.  I suspect your issue is bootstrap/startup code which all the items you listed dont really matter, are you in control of the bootstrap code and the linker script?  If not you should take control and/or understand who is in control of that, otherwise your c programs may not run at all...

Comment: All cool now after sorting out linker script and startup code. Thanks for the help.